# using google APIs within a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a project to make a chrome extension and the idea is to take notes and write to a Google Doc. So far, for getting started I've created a API key and am using a Client ID (web app option) to work locally using the template from Google's JavaScript quickstart HTML, see source:

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/js#python-2.x

I've since been messing around and made some functions and a popup.html that would be used for the extension popup. Now, I'd like to test this within the extension / browser environment and herein lies the issue. I would think you can get access to these APIs within the extension and still test and develop without publishing to the chrome store.

It seems I need a key in the manifest along with an oauth2, client_id, and scope. The latter I have, but I don't get how I can get a key for this? From the [developer documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/key/), it mentions that you can pack your extension and this gave me private key, is that the same thing? I should note too, that the process listed in the documentation doesn't work for me as in my local files the extension isn't in my system.

Moreover, I suspect I need to get the scripts to handle logins and authorize as well, but one step at a time here.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, that was all I needed.  I tried looking everywhere for something like that, but nothing was current or at least recent, which I could say this is the answer.  Although I guess this wasn't much of a question